# Which Object in UserDao while Autowiring it in Spring MVC if we have two Implementation classes and both have beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, Suppose we have a Dao named UserDao

```
public interface UserDao {

}
```

and it has two implementation classes UserDaoImpl and UserDaoImpl2

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

}

public class UserDaoImpl2 implements UserDao {

}
```

if we create beans of both these classes:

servelet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.usr.UserDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDao2" class="com.usr.UserDaoImpl2">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

and we have @Autowired it in my controller as

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;
}
```

Then UserDao has which implementatation's object UserDaoImpl or UserDaoImpl2.

Kindly help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

That should result in an error because Spring does not know which Bean to inject since there are multiple available.

To fix that you will need to either **set one as the primary** (the main one that should be injected when you don't specify more information so that Spring knows which one you want):

```xml
<beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.usr.UserDaoImpl" primary="true">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDao2" class="com.usr.UserDaoImpl2">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

This will inject a bean of class `com.usr.UserDaoImpl`.

Or you can also use **qualifiers** so that you can tell exactly which bean you want.

```xml
<beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.usr.UserDaoImpl">
    <qualifier value="one"/>
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDao2" class="com.usr.UserDaoImpl2">
    <qualifier value="two"/>
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

And in the dependant code:

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("two")
    UserDao userDao;
}
```

This will inject a bean of class `com.usr.UserDaoImpl2`.